# How to select only required columns in Default Edit Form option?

Tags: edit-form

I want only some columns to be displayed when I click on edit items option. It should be a customized form having only few columns to be edited. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have more options other than the jQuery hack:

**Option 1: custom edit form**

Create a new EditForm in SharePoint designer and set it as default.
To do this, in SPD go to your list, then Forms > New > Edit item form > set as default form. You can then customize the form and delete from the generated xslt/html code the fields you don't want to be editable.

**Option 2: content type management / hide columns**

Enable content types management. Using the browser UI, go to List settings > Advanced Settings > Allow management of content types > yes > OK.
Then, under content types, click on the content type (eg. Item), and click on each column you don't want to be editable, then set Hidden (Will not appear in forms).
Caveat: hidden columns won't appear in the newform either

Comment: I want all columns to be displayed in newform. I want only some columns to be displayed in edit item option.

Comment: Ok, then option 1 will do

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `ShowInEditForm` field property to `false` in order for a field to be not shown in the Edit Form.

**UPDATE**

`ShowInEditForm` property is not available through UI while creating a column. If you are restricted to creating columns through UI only, then you may have to hide columns through JQuery/Javascript
Place a content editor webpart or script editor webpart (2013) in the Edit form and use this script as an example to hide a field:

```
<script src="http://sp2010:90/JQuery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var locationField = $("input[title=Location]"); 
locationField.parent().parent().parent().hide();   
</script>
```

As can be seen the script needs JQuery to be placed in a library

Comment: And where will I get ShowInEditForm option?

Comment: How are you creating the field. In XML file, Programatically?? Through UI using content type or simply adding columns

Comment: By simply adding columns

Comment: This property is not available through UI while creating a column. If you are restricted to creating columns through UI only, then you may have to hide columns through JQuery/Javascript

Comment: See my updated answer

Comment: I would recommend against using the title property as a jQuery selector, as it may change if you switch to a different language in a multi-language site